# An error saying “You cannot define a correlation name 'payment' more than once” while taking export

Tags: magento, export, magento-1.9, export-to-csv, orders

I am trying to take an export of the orders in the magento backend but I am getting this error. Can anyone let me know How can I resolve this?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:61:"You cannot define a correlation name 'payment' more than once";i:1;s:2483:"#0 /home/uatemrco/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array, NULL)
#1 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php(373): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php(33): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array)
#3 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer->salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderGridC...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#6 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(590): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#7 /home/uatemrco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(565): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
#8 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#9 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(1011): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
#10 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(703): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
#11 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->exportCsvAction()
#12 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
#13 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/uatemrco/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}";s:3:"url";s:118:"/index.php/aksmsrrc/sales_order/exportCsv/key/9252bd3f9da8a80c055a8964c0c0be8c/internal_order_ids/4686,4685,4684,4683/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: I see `app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php` - if you could please share that code since it's pretty close to the top of the stack trace, that'd be good. Failing that, please contact whoever wrote that module and ask them for support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?